# laravel Token Mismatch error from within an iframe

Tags: php, laravel, iframe

I have a laravel app that is sitting in an iframe. On the login pages on IE and Safari i get a Token Mismatch error. I have read around and found that people have had the error and implemented P3P headers. If i do this in the VerifyCsrfToken it gets rid of the error but then the login doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should share the relevant code.